# How to prevent TextField from focusing on page load on NativeScript?

Tags: android, nativescript

I've tried a couple different ways to get my text field to stop focusing on page load. The keyboard does not show when the page loads up but the field's label moves up as if it was in focus. I tried the suggestion at the top of this [link](https://bradmartin.net/2016/10/12/preventing-the-android-keyboard-from-showing-on-page-load-in-nativescript-app/) but the field remained in focus. `onPageLoad` I also retrieved the TextField by Id and then called `setFocusable(false)` but this completely stops me from ever focusing on the element ever again. And android's `clearFocus` also doesn't do anything since the element still tries to focus. How can I get the field to stop focusing on Android? It is focusing on the Email Address field on page load.

```
    <Page 
    backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar="false" 
    backgroundColor="#222222" 
    loaded="onPageLoaded" 
    class="page" 
    actionBarHidden="true" 
    xmlns:Gradient="nativescript-gradient"
    xmlns:TIL="nativescript-textinputlayout">
    <GridLayout rows="*, auto, auto" columns="*">
        <GridLayout row="0" col="0" rows="auto, auto" columns="*" verticalAlignment="bottom" style="margin-bottom: 64dp;">
            <StackLayout row="0" col="0" style="margin-bottom: 16dp;">
                <Label class="h1 registration-app-title" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="bottom" textWrap="true" text="Repeat"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout row="1" col="0">
                <Label class="h3 registration-app-description" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="bottom" textWrap="true" text="Save articles to your playlist and listen to them anywhere."/>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
        <GridLayout row="1" col="0" rows="*, *, *, *" columns="*, *" class="registration-bottom">
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical" class="form" row="0" col="0" colSpan="2">
                        <TIL:TextInputLayout
                            class="text-input-layout"
                            hint="E-mail Address"
                            hintTextAppearance="StyledTIL"
                            >
                            <TextField 
                                id="text-field-email"
                                text="{{ email }}"
                                autocorrect="false" 
                                autocapitalizationType="none" 
                                keyboardType="email"
                                returnKeyType="next"/>
                        </TIL:TextInputLayout>

                        <TIL:TextInputLayout
                            class="text-input-layout"
                            hint="Password"
                            hintTextAppearance="StyledTIL"
                            marginBottom="30dp">
                            <TextField 
                                id="text-field-password"
                                text="{{ password }}"
                                secure="true"
                                autocapitalizationType="none"
                                returnKeyType="done"/>
                        </TIL:TextInputLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="form" row="1" col="0" colSpan="2" style="width: 80%;">
                <Gradient:Gradient direction="to right" colors="#FF51A0FF, #FF3F2AFF" class="gradient" style="margin-right: 14;">
                    <Button class="btn btn-primary"
                            id="register-email"
                            text="Sign Up"
                            tap="register" />
                </Gradient:Gradient>
                <Gradient:Gradient direction="to right" colors="#FF51A0FF, #FF3F2AFF" class="gradient">
                    <Button class="btn btn-primary"
                            id="email"
                            text="Log In"
                            tap="authenticate"/>
                </Gradient:Gradient>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical" class="form" row="2" col="0" colSpan="2">
                        <Button class="btn btn-alternate"
                                id="facebook"
                                text="Connect with Facebook"
                                tap="authenticate"
                                textTransform="none"/>

                        <Button class="btn btn-alternate"
                                id="google"
                                text="Connect with Google"
                                tap="authenticate"
                                textTransform="none" />
            </StackLayout>
            <GridLayout row="3" col="0" colSpan="2" rows="*" columns="*">
                <Label class="h3 skip-step-label" 
                       id="anonymous"
                       row="0" 
                       col="0" 
                       text="Skip this step" 
                       tap="authenticate"/>
            </GridLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `dismissSoftInput` from utils module in your page's `navigatedTo` event.

```
import { ad } as utils from "utils/utils";
ad.dismissSoftInput();
```

**Update:** Above will just hide keyboard and will not remove focus completely. You always need another view which you can focus in order to remove focus from the TextField. Here is an example how you can do that,

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=sgXKCB

Comment: No. Unfortunately that didn't work. I added an image showing the input that shows the cursor but the keyboard isn't visible. Sorry the image is so large. Don't know how to make it smaller on here.

Comment: Do you want to just hide the keyboard or want to remove focus completely? If you are planning to remove focus you can't do it until you have another focusable view.

Try adding linear layout (by building a custom component) with focusable true.

Comment: I would like for both fields to not be in focus when the page loads. I basically want the email address field to not display a cursor and make it look like the password field; user has to explicitly click to start editing a field.